# How to repaint skin in OpenCV?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I am using OpenCV for seamlessclone. I need to repaint the skin in a different color, for example it will be rgb (139,69,19). How to do it with relief and texture?

[image: EXAMPLE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though your question seems to lack effort (what have you tried yourself?), it seemed like a fun exercise so I wrote some code that lets you alter the rgb values of the image using sliders.
The sliders range from 0 to 510. First 255 is subtracted, then it's added to the rgb values of the image. This means that values below 255 are a subtraction. The values are clipped to the min and max values (0 and 255).
This process changes the color while maintaining texture and lighting.

Result:
[image]

Code:

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    # load image
    img = cv2.imread("fGhx4.png")
    # create window
    cv2.namedWindow("IMG")

    #set default values
    red = 0
    green = 0
    blue = 0

    # functions to set values
    def setBlue(val):
            global blue
            blue = val-255
            colorShift()

    def setGreen(val):
            global green
            green = val-255
            colorShift()

    def setRed(val):
            global red
            red = val-255
            colorShift()

    # function that performs the colorshift
    def colorShift():
            # create working copy
            res = img.copy()

            # modify hue
            # converted layer to uint16 to accomodate values larger than 255
            blue_array = np.uint16(res[:,:,0])+blue
            # clip min and max values - prevents unwanted wrap around
            blue_array = np.where(blue_array > 255 , 255, blue_array)
            blue_array = np.where(blue_array < 0, 0, blue_array)
            # convert back to uint8 and assign to image layer
            res[:,:,0] = np.uint8(blue_array)

            # modify green  - same process 
            green_layer = np.uint16(res[:,:,1])+green
            green_layer = np.where(green_layer > 255 , 255, green_layer)
            green_layer = np.where(green_layer < 0, 0, green_layer)
            res[:,:,1] = np.uint8(green_layer)

            # modify red - same process 
            red_layer = np.uint16(res[:,:,2])+red
            red_layer = np.where(red_layer > 255 , 255, red_layer)
            red_layer = np.where(red_layer < 0, 0, red_layer)
            res[:,:,2] = np.uint8(red_layer)

            # display result
            cv2.imshow("IMG", res)


    #create trackbars to modify values
    cv2.createTrackbar("Blue","IMG",255,510,setBlue)
    cv2.createTrackbar("Green","IMG",255,510,setGreen)
    cv2.createTrackbar("Red","IMG",255,510,setRed)

    # display initial image
    cv2.imshow("IMG", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I tried the changeColor function, which disappointed me a bit, I thought it really implements the solution you described. Thanks, awesome function.